# how can i fetch table from doctype to another doc in erpnext

Tags: javascript, java, erp, erpnext

I have 2 table in 2 different docs and I have filed linked with them so , how can I fetch the table a in doc a to table b in doc b when I select on doc 2 my data
I ll give you example :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI7RH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBUZr.png)
in "From Template" I chose my data and it didn't fetch branch or cost center

I try client script but a lot of errors and it didn't get the data please help me
thanks ..